# Jquery Accordion widget - remove the icon and padding

Tags: jquery, icons, accordion, padding

I'm new to jquery and i'm trying to find out if it's possible to create simple accordion without the arrow icon and without padding at all inside the accordion content.

I want to use the whole content space, and it seems like jquery accordion widget auto create some padding as the width of the arrow icon.

Thanks!
Lior

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All you need to do is add your own CSS to remove the icon and padding, or override the default CSS with something like this:

```
#accordion .ui-icon { display: none; }
#accordion .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 0; }
```

if `accordion` was the ID you where you called the function (see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BG9j5/))

Oh and if you want to remove the content padding, use this CSS:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect!, screen real-estate taken back (padding:0); which is a necessity if you're using the accordion for navigation.

Answer (score 49):

to remove the icons you better use

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    icons: false
});
```

Comment: I had to do this:
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#leftmenu_0_accordion").accordion({
                icons: false
            });
        });

Comment: I didn't see this answer until I had already upvoted the one above. IMHO this is the more correct solution.

Comment: Rather than add them to hide them with css, do this and not add them in the first place. Great job.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
     icons: null
});
```

worked for me